# Java how to parse uint8 in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a **uint8** *(unsigned 8 bit integer)* coming in from a UDP packet. Java only uses signed primitives. How do I parse this data structure correctly with java?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply read it as as a byte and then convert to an int.

```
byte in = udppacket.getByte(0); // whatever goes here
int uint8 = in & 0xFF;
```

The bitmask is needed, because otherwise, values with bit 8 set to 1 will be converted to a negative int. Example:

```
This:                                   10000000
Will result in: 11111111111111111111111110000000
```

So when you afterwards apply the bitmask 0xFF to it, the leading 1's are getting cancelled out. For your information: `0xFF == 0b11111111`

Comment: Thank you, this was very informative. I appreciate your response

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

`0xFF & number` will treat the number as unsigned byte. But the resultant type is `int`

Answer (score 5):

You can store 8-bit in a `byte`  If you really need to converted it to an unsigned value (and often you don't) you can use a mask

```
byte b = ...
int u = b & 0xFF; // unsigned 0 .. 255 value
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
int value = eightBits & 0xff;
```

The `&` operator (like all integer operators in Java) up-casts `eightBits` to an `int` (by sign-extending the sign bit). Since this would turn values greater than 0x7f into negative `int` values, you need to then mask off all but the lowest 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply parse it into a `short` or an `int`, which have enough range to hold all the values of an unsigned byte.