# How is this variable used as an int and as an array in cpp?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to port some code from C++ to Java. The code looks like this in C++:

```
  uint8_t r, g, b, bit, limit, *ptr;

  ...

  if(y < nRows) {
    // Data for the upper half of the display is stored in the lower bits of each byte.
    ptr = &matrixbuff[backindex][y * WIDTH * (nPlanes - 1) + x]; // Base addr
    // Plane 0 is a tricky case -- its data is spread about,
    // stored in least two bits not used by the other planes.
    ptr[WIDTH*2] &= ~B00000011;           // Plane 0 R,G mask out in one op
    if(r & 1) ptr[WIDTH*2] |=  B00000001; // Plane 0 R: 64 bytes ahead, bit 0
    if(g & 1) ptr[WIDTH*2] |=  B00000010; // Plane 0 G: 64 bytes ahead, bit 1
    if(b & 1) ptr[WIDTH]   |=  B00000001; // Plane 0 B: 32 bytes ahead, bit 0
    else      ptr[WIDTH]   &= ~B00000001; // Plane 0 B unset; mask out
    // The remaining three image planes are more normal-ish.
    // Data is stored in the high 6 bits so it can be quickly
    // copied to the DATAPORT register w/6 output lines.
    for(; bit < limit; bit <<= 1) {
      *ptr &= ~B00011100;            // Mask out R,G,B in one op
      if(r & bit) *ptr |= B00000100; // Plane N R: bit 2
      if(g & bit) *ptr |= B00001000; // Plane N G: bit 3
      if(b & bit) *ptr |= B00010000; // Plane N B: bit 4
      ptr  += WIDTH;                 // Advance to next bit plane
    }
  } else {
    // Data for the lower half of the display is stored in the upper
    // bits, except for the plane 0 stuff, using 2 least bits.
    ptr = &matrixbuff[backindex][(y - nRows) * WIDTH * (nPlanes - 1) + x];
    *ptr &= ~B00000011;                  // Plane 0 G,B mask out in one op
    if(r & 1)  ptr[WIDTH] |=  B00000010; // Plane 0 R: 32 bytes ahead, bit 1
    else       ptr[WIDTH] &= ~B00000010; // Plane 0 R unset; mask out
    if(g & 1) *ptr        |=  B00000001; // Plane 0 G: bit 0
    if(b & 1) *ptr        |=  B00000010; // Plane 0 B: bit 0
    for(; bit < limit; bit <<= 1) {
      *ptr &= ~B11100000;            // Mask out R,G,B in one op
      if(r & bit) *ptr |= B00100000; // Plane N R: bit 5
      if(g & bit) *ptr |= B01000000; // Plane N G: bit 6
      if(b & bit) *ptr |= B10000000; // Plane N B: bit 7
      ptr  += WIDTH;                 // Advance to next bit plane
    }
  }
```

I don't understand the use of `ptr`

It is declared as an int:

`uint8_t ... *ptr;`

Then it is set to some value

`ptr = &matrixbuff...`

**but** then it seems to be used as an array

`ptr[WIDTH*2] &= ~B00000011;`

*What?* Can someone explain please (and then is this possible in Java)

Comment: It's declared as a *pointer* to an `uint8_t` - which in this case seems to point to an array

Comment: this isn't array behaviour though: `*ptr &= ~B00011100; ` right?

Comment: Java does not use numeric pointers, but abstract references to objects. You can't do pointer arithmetic like you are doing here.

Comment: The line `*ptr &= ~B00011100;` is equivalent to `ptr[0] &= ~B00011100;`

Comment: In order to port this code, you are going to have to essentially ignore it and focus on what it is actually doing, then see if you can do that in Java using a ByteBuffer or something like that. So focus on the comments, and then research what you actually can do in Java that will accomplish the same task

Comment: @Blundell you can port the binary literals with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html 
If all of this pointer arithmetic is just for array access, than you actually can port it pretty close to as is using an index of 0 as the initial ptr, it's just when the pointer is supposed to represent a specific memory address (like a driver) that you have to use something like a MappedByteBuffer.

Comment: @Novaterata Yeah I was just going to port it language wise and then worry about understanding it later, but i think you're right its using specific mem addresses, so i might have to take the alternative route. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Blundell Also, one thing to be careful of is that Java types are all signed except for char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is declared as an int:
>
> ```
> uint8_t ... *ptr;
> ```

Unlike Java and many other languages deriving their syntax from C, C++ lets you declare variables of different type in a single declaration. Although `r`, `g`, `b`, etc. are all `uint8_t`, `ptr` is not, because of the asterisk prefixed to it. This prefix makes `ptr` a *pointer* to `uint8_t`.

> Then it is set to some value
>
> ```
> ptr = &matrixbuff[some_index]
> ```

Again, the prefix provides a clue: this time, it is prefix operator `&`, which takes an address of the expression that follows.

> but then it seems to be used as an array
>
> ```
> ptr[WIDTH*2] &= ~B00000011;
> ```

That's right, too, because C++ lets you use a pointer as if it were an array. In some cases, it lets you use an array as if it were a pointer, too, but generally the two concepts should not be confused.

Long story short, if you have a pointer `p` of type `T*` and an integer value `i`, an expression `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p+i)`, and refers to a value of type `T` at the offset of `i` sizes of `T` from the address pointed to by `p`. Hence, pointer's behavior mimics that of an array.

In Java you would have to translate operations on `ptr` to operations on `matrixbuff` with indexes computed as a combination of the index on `ptr` and the index of `ptr` itself, e.g.

```
ptr[WIDTH]
```

would become

```
matrixbuff[backindex][y * WIDTH * (nPlanes - 1) + x + WIDTH]
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^
//                              Origin                Index
```

Answer (score 1):

When an array is declared, the memory is contiguously allocated. If you declare a variable like `char *c` in C++, you can actually assign it a string like :
`c = "abcd";`
Here each letter `a-d` are stored in contiguous memory locations, hence you can access them as `c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3]` , in fact they are : `*c, *(c+1), *(c+2), *(c+3)`.

In Java, you may declare the `uint8_t *ptr` as `byte[] ptr;` You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071361/java-how-to-parse-uint8-in-java) why `byte` is appropriate for `uint8_t` ?